# Can I disallow the ability for a user to select/see a Chrome autofill option when using google places API? It's causing incomplete address submissions

Tags: autofill, google-places-autocomplete

My site collects address information through our gravity form. We use the google places API to suggest the address as the user types. However, when Chrome users click the field it overlays their auto-fill options for saved addresses. Most times these addresses come in as "Street number..Street Name" as opposed to the google places API showing city, state, zip after that. This is for a moving company so kind of important to know what city the lead is coming in from.

My question is, is there any way to disallow the user's auto-fill box from showing, regardless of their chrome browser settings (autofill on/off)? So if they click the field for the "Address" nothing happens, thus they are forced to start typing and clicking the suggested address once the correct one populates?